# How to generate normally distributed random number

Tags: numerics, distributions

I want to sample or return random number from a distribution which is normally distributed with mean of zero and standard deviation of 1. I am using

```
 RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]
```

Is this right one? Is it very similar to using excel Rand() function?

Comment: Maybe start with documentation. `NormalDistribution` has an example with `RandomVariate` which is also a first tip under `RandomReal` page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1]]
```

If you want 10 such numbers:

```
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 10]
```

Answering the question below:

```
RandomVariate[TruncatedDistribution[{0, 1}, NormalDistribution[0, 1]], 12]
```

Comment: Thanks for info. Can I restrict the generated random no between 0 and 1 with mean of zero and standard deviation of 1. I generally add excel Rand () 12times and substract 6 to get such distribution. Is there a equivalent way in Mathematica

Comment: @Kausik Excel's `rand()` function gives you a *uniformly distributed* result. To do exactly what you do in Excel in *Mathematica* (and plot the histogram to see that it is correct): `Histogram[Total[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10000, 12}], {2}] - 6]`. The way David shows it, *Mathematica* generates these random variates directly already with a normal distribution, so there is no need to truncate the distribution or sum the variates obtained. (But you can if you want.)